# TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js, undefined, nan, fetch-api

I'm getting issues with this code. It gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

```
dotenv.config();
  
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", async (msg) => {
 
  const tokens = msg.content.split(" ");

  
  if (tokens[0] === "!gif") {
   
    const keywords = tokens.slice(1, tokens.length).join(" ");
    
    const url = `https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=${keywords}&key=${process.env.EK3M4TY0S70Y}&limit=10`;
    
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    const result = await response.json();
    
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length);
    
    msg.channel.send(result.results[index].url);
  }
});
```

Comment: Im new here and i was seeking for some help. I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined and im not sure how to fix this

Comment: Try logging your result variable and see what you get.  It’s either some sort of error or it’s not the data structure that you are expecting.  Your code implies that result is an array (since you access result.length) and that it is an object with a property results which is an array (since you access result.results[index]).  Your error message implies that neither is true!  You get an index of NaN when multiplying by result.length and the “of undefined” means that result.results is undefined.

Comment: I'm looking at the API and you do want `result.results.length` instead of `result.length`.  I'm not sure why you are getting `result.results` as `undefined`.  Possibly a malformed query.  You probably want to use `encodeURIComponent` on `keywords`.  But your code works for me after that change: https://codesandbox.io/s/tenor-api-random-cat-gif-tke9x?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Oh!!! Such an error message suggests that your code has several errors!

Answer (score 2):

#### Property `NaN`

The `NaN` in your code is the variable `index`.  If `result.length` is `undefined` then `Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)` will be `NaN`.

When you try to get an item from the array you are using `result.results[index]` which implies that `result` is an object with a `results` property which is an array.  So the `result` itself is not an array and accessing `result.length` doesn't make sense.  You would want result.results.length`.

#### Of `undefined`

The error "Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined" comes from `result.results[index]`.  so if `index` is the `NaN` property then `result.results` is the `undefined` value.  The Tenor API *should* return an object with a `results` property, so this is likely due to a malformed request.  If you have an invalid `key` for example, your response will be an object with a property `error` and no `results`.  You could also have an invalid `q`, so you'll want to escape it with `encodeURIComponent`.

I don't have enough information to know why the request is failing for you, but we can check that we have an `array` and `console.log` the result otherwise so that you can inspect it (or `throw` an `Error`).  When you improve the code a bit more you'll want to introduce `try`/`catch` blocks.

```js
const testFunc = async (msgContent, apiKey = "") => {
  const tokens = msgContent.split(" ");

  if (tokens[0] === "!gif") {
    const keywords = encodeURIComponent(
      tokens.slice(1, tokens.length).join(" ")
    );

    // seems to work with no key at all
    const url = `https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=${keywords}&key=${apiKey}&limit=10`;

    const response = await fetch(url);

    const result = await response.json();
    
    if ("results" in result) {
      const images = result.results;

      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

      return images[index].url;
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid Response", result);
    }
  }
};

testFunc("!gif cat", "").then(console.log);
```